# replace -O1 parameter with others in gcc to inline a function

Tags: gcc, optimization, arm, inline, cortex-m

I use arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.8.4

```
Target: arm-none-eabi
Configured with: /home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/src/gcc/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-native --libexecdir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-native/lib --infodir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info --mandir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/man --htmldir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/html --pdfdir=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-native/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/pdf --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-plugins --disable-decimal-float --disable-libffi --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-threads --disable-tls --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-newlib --with-headers=yes --with-python-dir=share/gcc-arm-none-eabi --with-sysroot=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/install-native/arm-none-eabi --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --with-gmp=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-mpfr=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-mpc=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-isl=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-cloog=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-libelf=/home/build/work/GCC-4-8-build/build-native/host-libs/usr --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-pkgversion='GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors' --with-multilib-list=armv6-m,armv7-m,armv7e-m,armv7-r
Thread model: single
gcc version 4.8.4 20140725 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_8-branch revision 213147] (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors)
```

and I wrote a simple sample c file:

```
volatile int v;
static inline void a(void)
{
    v = 4;
}

static inline void b(void)
{
    a();
}

int main(void)
{
    a();
    b();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with

```
 /opt/toolchain/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall  -g3 -std=gnu99 -Wa,-adhlns="inline_test.o.lst" -MMD -MP -MF"inline_test.d" -MT"inline_test.o" -c -o inline_test.o inline_test.c
```

and the function are not inlined
instead if I add `-O1` they are.

using `--help=optimizers` parameter I can see that the parameters enabled by `-O1` are:

```
  -fcombine-stack-adjustments       [enabled]
  -fcompare-elim                    [enabled]
  -fcprop-registers                 [enabled]
  -fdefer-pop                       [enabled]
  -fforward-propagate               [enabled]
  -fguess-branch-probability        [enabled]
  -fif-conversion                   [enabled]
  -fif-conversion2                  [enabled]
  -finline-functions-called-once    [enabled]
  -fipa-profile                     [enabled]
  -fipa-pure-const                  [enabled]
  -fipa-reference                   [enabled]
  -fmerge-constants                 [enabled]
  -fomit-frame-pointer              [enabled]
  -fsched-pressure                  [enabled]
  -fsection-anchors                 [enabled]
  -fshrink-wrap                     [enabled]
  -fsplit-wide-types                [enabled]
  -ftree-bit-ccp                    [enabled]
  -ftree-ccp                        [enabled]
  -ftree-ch                         [enabled]
  -ftree-copy-prop                  [enabled]
  -ftree-copyrename                 [enabled]
  -ftree-dce                        [enabled]
  -ftree-dominator-opts             [enabled]
  -ftree-dse                        [enabled]
  -ftree-fre                        [enabled]
  -ftree-sink                       [enabled]
  -ftree-slsr                       [enabled]
  -ftree-sra                        [enabled]
  -ftree-ter                        [enabled]
```

So I try to compile removing `-O1`, but adding all these other options:

```
/opt/toolchain/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall  -fcombine-stack-adjustments -fcompare-elim -fcprop-registers -fdefer-pop -fforward-propagate -fguess-branch-probability -fif-conversion -fif-conversion2 -finline-functions-called-once -fipa-profile -fipa-pure-const -fipa-reference -fmerge-constants -fomit-frame-pointer -fsched-pressure -fsection-anchors -fshrink-wrap -fsplit-wide-types -ftree-bit-ccp -ftree-ccp -ftree-ch -ftree-copy-prop -ftree-copyrename -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse -ftree-fre -ftree-sink -ftree-slsr -ftree-sra -ftree-ter   -g3 -std=gnu99 -Wa,-adhlns="inline_test.o.lst" -MMD -MP -MF"inline_test.d" -MT"inline_test.o" -c -o inline_test.o inline_test.c
```

but the functions are not inlined.

Which other parameters I need to replace `-O1`?

best regards

Max

Comment: ["Not all optimizations are controlled directly by a flag."](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a guarantee but try -finline-functions.